# Equivalent of checking quaternion is valid in tf2

Tags: ros, ros2, quaternion, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an equivalent function to `assertQuaternionValid()` in tf2? I suppose I could just re-implement the source code for the function using tf2 equivalents? http://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/tf_8h_source.html#l00486

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386824/equivalent-of-checking-quaternion-is-valid-in-tf2/) by [jn42](https://answers.ros.org/users/85101/jn42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2021-09-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-19**:
There is a thread that may be interesting to you:

https://github.com/ros/geometry2/pull/196

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-19**:
I'm having trouble understanding this idea that a calculation should be refused because the quaternion is slightly un-normalized. It seems reasonable to log a warning if you think that characteristic is important, but by my thinking you should proceed with the calculation anyway.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2023-05-13**:
Re-implementing that source code in python:

```
q = transform_stamped.transform.rotation
q_norm_error = abs(q.x * q.x + q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z + q.w * q.w - 1.0)
text = f"quaternion norm error {q_norm_error:0.6f}, {q}".replace("\n", ", ")
if q_norm_error > 0.01:
    ...
```

Probably converting the quaternion to the transformations.py array representation and doing a dot with itself is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general with tf2 it's recommended to use a native linear math library which has an internal representation of the quaternion and as such should have logic for normalizing and checking the normalization of the quaternion. The API of tf2 is specifically scoped down to be specific to the buffer etc and not random linear math problem.

Re: why normalized. @Mike Scheutzow the reason to rejecting storing non-normalized quaterions into the storage is because they can effect future computations in ways that are untraceable to users. You can find more info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667783/quaternion-and-normalization

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jn42](https://answers.ros.org/users/85101/jn42/) on 2021-09-20**:
Ah ok the separation of concerns makes sense for why tf2 didn't port over an equivalent function. Thank you!

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-20**:
@tfoote Thank you for the interesting link. I learned some new things about quaternions.